# POSIX-compliant shell equivalent to Bash "while read -d $'\0' ..."?

Tags: bash, shell, find, pipe, sh

I'm trying to make a Bash script strictly POSIX-compliant, i.e. removing any potential "[Bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)" by using `checkbashisms -px ${script_filename}`. In the given file, I walk through a directory using `find` and then pipe each file path to `read` using `\0` as a delimiter by using `-print0` in order to be able to handle filenames containing newline characters:

```
find . -print0 | while read -d $'\0' inpath
do
    echo "Reading path \"${inpath}\"."
done
```

However, [`checkbashisms`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/checkbashisms.1.html) doesn't like this because [the option `-d` isn't strictly POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html):

> possible bashism in ... line *n* (read with option other than -r)

How can I write equivalent code which is POSIX-compliant, i.e. to read output from `find` using a non-newline delimiter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `-d` option, `read` builtin cannot read null terminated data.

You can do this in `find + xargs`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'for f; do echo "Reading path \"$f\""; done' _
```

Or if you don't mind spawning a shell for each file use just `find`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -exec sh -c 'echo "Reading path \"$1\""' - {} \;
```

Comment: The first suggestion will set `$0`, `$1`, ... `${!#}` so `for f;` will *not* read the first passed value. You can fix this by sending an empty argument to sh: `find ... | xargs -0 sh -c '...' ""`

Comment: Actually I've tested that command on 2 different systems and `find . -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'echo "$@"'` does print all the filenames.

Comment: I assume that's because the first is the current directory. But with a filter like `-type f` you would notice a difference.

Comment: Yes you are spot on, thanks so much (edited the answer with `-mindepth 1`)

Comment: You don't actually need to spawn a separate shell; e.g., `find . -mindepth 1 -exec /bin/echo "Reading path \"{}\""` would work as well.

Comment: Yes if just `echo` is the requirement then that will work but usually one needs to do more while iterating each file.

Comment: Foregoing portability, `read -d` is generally preferable over `xargs -0`, offering better exit status semantics.