# Check last character of a string

Tags: string, bash, shell, sh

Is there a built-in POSIX equivalent for this bashism?

```
my_string="Here is a string"
last_character=${my_string: -1}
```

I keep seeing things like this recommended, but they seem like hacks.

```
last_character=$(echo -n "$my_string" | tail -c 1)
last_character=$(echo -n "$my_string" | grep -o ".$")
```

But, maybe a hack is all we have with POSIX shells?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [POSIX-compliant shell equivalent to Bash "while read -d $'\0' ..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342833/posix-compliant-shell-equivalent-to-bash-while-read-d-0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you **really** have to do it POSIX only:

```
my_string="Here is a string"
last_character=${my_string#"${my_string%?}"}
```

What it does is essentially removing `$my_string` sans its last character from the beginning of the `$my_string`, leaving you with only the last character.

Comment: Thanks, still a hack but at least it's a hack with only parameter expansion!

Comment: @miken32 - hackish, definitely, but beats piping and invoking other commands. It's far less versatile, tho, but that's POSIX for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to check what is the last character and then act on its value, then the `case ... esac` construct is a portable way to express it.

Answer (score 0):

```
num=`echo $my_string | wc -c `
let num-=1
last=`echo $my_string | cut -c$num`
echo $last
```

assumpting:  (its lastchar here) is the string for which u need the last charactor for. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: This breaks if the input string contains a linebreak.